# Strip URL of JavaScript

Tags: javascript, anchor, trim

I have a URL that contains a lot of JavaScript.

I want to strip the URL of all JavaScript using of course JavaScript!

Here's my HTML

```
<a id="product_photo_zoom_url" href="javascript:OpenNewWindow('/PhotoDetails.asp?ShowDesc=N&PhotoNumber=3&ProductCode=TCP65GT30', 640, 480); void(0);" title="" rel="lightbox">
```

Basically I'd like the URL to just look like this:

```
 <a id="product_photo_zoom_url" href="/PhotoDetails.asp?ShowDesc=N&PhotoNumber=3&ProductCode=TCP65GT30" title="" rel="lightbox">
```

There are many instances of this so trimming off the first and last ten characters would not be sufficient.

Get Element by ID product_photo_zoom_url would be fine.

Thank you for helping me!

Comment: Does the solution need to be in raw js? or are you using other js libraries such as jquery.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just get the text between single quotes:

```
var href = "javascript:OpenNewWindow('/PhotoDetails.asp?ShowDesc=N&PhotoNumber=3&ProductCode=TCP65GT30', 640, 480); void(0);";
var url = /'(.+?)'/.exec(href)[1];
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/minitech/QJQRa/)

Also, you shouldn't use mutliple elements with the same `id`, it's invalid. `id`s are meant to be unique. You should be using `class`es instead. If you can, you should change them.

Comment: How can I make this apply to anchors with the id product_photo_zoom_url?

Comment: Nice, very lean. You can modify that with JQuery to find all the anchor tags using something like $('a[href^="javascript"]').each(function(){})

Comment: @user1090389: Since you're using jQuery, try this: http://jsfiddle.net/minitech/QJQRa/1/

Comment: Why would you use jQuery for anything but the line 4? You can delete the function, and replace that mess of `$().prop...`s with `this.href=/'(.+?)'/.exec(this.href)[1];`.

Comment: @skier88: Not enough jQuery :) I hate mixing the two anyway, doesn't feel right.

Comment: lol ... at least you're honest. I would be in the opposite camp - the thought of using a 90kb library to run a regex and a loop makes me shiver.

Comment: also, I know it's faster than classes, but do you really need to use invalid html?

Comment: @skier88: No, actually I dislike jQuery so much that I made my own library :) And I can't believe I forgot to include that, edited in!

Comment: Yeah, I was actually just skimming it. Interesting that you opted to sort of combine css and xpath into something new - maybe not the best idea for a widely distributed library, but, IMHO, a really good idea if you want something efficient for your own use.

Answer (score 2):

If you just want it to run on the one anchor, you can do this:

```
var el=document.getElementById('product_photo_zoom_url');
el.href=/'(.*?)'/.exec(el.href)[1];
```